# Linux Log all the su to root messages

Tags: linux, logging, linux-mint

I am learning how to use log files in Linux 
and now I am trying to configure a file called *Mysu.log* in */dev/log/*

In this file I have to log all ***the su to root messages***

I have logged different types of services in the */etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf* file but I don't understand how I can log these commands.

If you have any solution how I could configure this root messages, please post.

Comment: My */var/log/auth.log* contains a message like *Successful su for root by $USER* for every successful call to `su`. I guess you have to look if *PAM* (pluggable authentication module) generates such events.