# How to enable su logging in CentOS release 6.6

Tags: linux, logging, centos6, su

how can i enable logging to a file every time as user uses the su command to switch to root or any other user?

Previously i was achieving this by adding an entry to cs-auth file as below

```
echo "session required pam_unix.so" >> /etc/pam.d/cs-auth
```

But in the CentOS release 6.6 release i have a system-auth file so what change needs to be made to system-auth file such that i can enable su logging?

Found a similar question but no suitable answer.
[Linux Log all the su to root messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681981/linux-log-all-the-su-to-root-messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

su logging is by default present in centos 6.6 machine and can be added by adding the below entry

```
echo "session required pam_unix.so"
```

to /etc/pam.d/system-auth and logs are present in the file /var/log/secure.